# Query does cartesian join unless

Tags: oracle, join, cartesian

I've got a query that's supposed to return 2 rows.  However, it returns 48 rows.  It's acting like one of the tables that's being joined isn't there.  But if I add a column from that table to the select clause, with no changes to the from or where parts of the query, it returns 2 rows.

Here's what "Explain plan" says without the "m.*" in the select:
[image: Explain Plan before]

Here it is again after adding m.* in the select:
[image: Explain Plan after]

Can anybody explain why it should behave this way?

**Update**: We only had this problem on one system and not another.  The DBA verified that the one with the problem is running optimizer_features_enable set to 10.2.0.5, and the one where it doesn't happen is running optimizer_features_enable set to 10.2.0.4.  Unfortunately the customer site is running 10.2.0.5.

Comment: What it is doing is obvious: the first query has removed the join to `mastersources` and `mastersource_function` entirely along with the filter in the Where clause. Why it is doing it is perplexing.

Comment: Correction, it has removed the join to `mastersources`. In the first query it still has the filter on MF.function but the join is clearly missing.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, that's what I figured as well, but the million dollar question is why.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the result disparity if you reverse the order of the joins?

Comment: @Thomas, the query was initially written with the tables in the order accountsource, mastersource, mastersource_function, accountenrollment and I re-ordered it as you see above to see if it helped.  It didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about a join elimination that was introduced in 10gR2:

> Table elimination (alternately called
>   "join elimination") removes redundant
>   tables from a query. A table is
>   redundant if its columns are only
>   referenced to in join predicates, and
>   it is guaranteed that those joins
>   neither filter nor expand the
>   resulting rows. There are several
>   cases where Oracle will eliminate a
>   redundant table.

Maybe that's kind of related bug or so. Have a look at [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/why_are_some_of_the_tables_in_my_query_missing_from_the_plan) article.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Are there any relevant constraints that are NOVALIDATE and RELY, and have data that violates the constraints?  Perhaps Oracle uses table elimination when it thinks it can, even though it shouldn't.  (I haven't been able to create a test case for this, but it seems like it should be possible to make Oracle return the wrong results.  Does anybody have an example to demonstrate this?)

Comment: Yes, it can happen for rely-constraints when the query_rewrite_integrity parameter is set to TRUSTED or STALE_TOLERATED.

Comment: Response from our DBA: I checked the configurations suggested, in particular the query_rewrite_parameter (which does not apply because we are not using materialized views and it is set to enforced anyway) and changing the _optimizer_transitivity_retain parameter to true which did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. What are the constraints ?

Logically, if all rows in MASTERSOURCE_FUNCTION had the function NON-OSDA then that wouldn't exclude any rows (or if none had that value, then all rows would be excluded).

Going one step further, if every row in MASTERSOURCE had one or zero NON-OSDA rows in MASTERSOURCE_FUNCTION, then it should be a candidate for exclusion. But there would also need to be a one-to-one between the MASTERSOURCE ID and NAME.

I'd pull the ROWIDs from ACCOUNTSOURCE for the 48 rows, then track the MASTERSOURCE ID and NAME and see on what grounds those rows are being duplicated or not excluded. That is, are there 12 duplicate names in MASTERSOURCE where it is expected to be unique through a NOVALIDATE constraint.

Comment: In the first case, it's acting as if there is no MASTERSOURCE join at all, and returning every MASTERSOURCE_FUNCTION row with 'NON-OSDA' regardless of what the sourcename is.

Comment: I can see that from the plan. Seeing the constraints would indicate why it thinks the MASTERSOURCE join is redundant.